# jQuery tables sort by time

Tags: jquery, sorting

im using jquery tables and i want to sort data based on date column and time column to shown the latest data first.

Comment: **[This](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/938/need-to-sort-on-time)** might help you..

Comment: I would suggest you to have time and date in same column. and then sort the values as shown here,https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18